# Variable inaccessible due to protection level

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a VB.Net

```
Private Function generateXMLSchema()
    Dim generatedXmlSchema As String = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:glob="http://sap.com/xi/SAPGlobal20/Global"><soapenv:Header/>" & _
        "<soapenv:Body>" & _
            "<glob:RouteBundleMaintainRequest_sync_V1>" & _
                "<Route actionCode="01">" & _
                    "<Name>tEST 250502</Name>" & _
                    "<RouteTypeCode>2</RouteTypeCode>" & _
                "</Route>" & _
            "</glob:RouteBundleMaintainRequest_sync_V1>" & _
        "</soapenv:Body>" & _
    "</soapenv:Envelope>"

    Return generatedXmlSchema
End Function
```

At `Return generatedXmlSchema` I am getting an error : **generatedXmlSchema is not Declared. It may be inaccessible due to protection level**

Can anybody tell me the issue?

---

Updated with Double Quote, Still the same error

```
Private Function generateXMLSchema()
    Dim genXmlSchema As String = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:glob=""http://sap.com/xi/SAPGlobal20/Global"><soapenv:Header/>" & _
        "<soapenv:Body>" & _
            "<glob:RouteBundleMaintainRequest_sync_V1>" & _
                "<Route actionCode="01">" & _
                    "<Name>tEST 250502</Name>" & _
                    "<RouteTypeCode>2</RouteTypeCode>" & _
                "</Route>" & _
            "</glob:RouteBundleMaintainRequest_sync_V1>" & _
        "</soapenv:Body>" & _
    "</soapenv:Envelope>"

    Return genXmlSchema
End Function
```

Comment: Your need to use double quotes, eg `"xmlns:glob=""https://mywebsite.com""><soapenv:Header/>"`

Comment: If it was really VB.NET you'd get a compiler error like 'cannot use local variable with same name as function`

Comment: @p3tch : I did the same As you asked , Please check the Updated part in the question

Comment: That looks more likely to be  VBA than VBScript. Please clarify.  All your function tries to do is return a string. In VBA you'd write it like this: `Private Function generateXMLSchema() AS String` then at the end `generateXMLSchema = genXmlSchema`. It makes no sense to return that error when your code won't even compile... and it's just trying to return a string.

Comment: this is VB.Net. I edited tags. see also answer

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid : Its VB script , The File where I am writing has .vb as extension.
I create a Button in the Ribbon . then Double clicked on the button to create this file. (I am very new to this technology).

Comment: It's definitely not VBScript! it's most likely VB.Net. I will edit tags again. vbscript has extension `.vbs`. `.vb` is most likely VB.Net

Comment: VBScript runs in WScript.EXE or CScript.exe and is not compiled. VBA runs inside office. VB.Net is compiled. VBA, VBScript and VB.Net are different languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must double quote every occurrence of a quote as a string delimiter:

```
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" -> ""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/""

"http://sap.com/xi/SAPGlobal20/Global" -> ""http://sap.com/xi/SAPGlobal20/Global""

"01" -> ""01""
```

that said, this function is `Private` so it must be called within the same `Class` it belongs to

all that above pour the following:

```
Public Class Class1

    Sub main()
        Console.WriteLine(generateXMLSchema())
    End Sub

    Private Function generateXMLSchema()
        Dim generatedXmlSchema As String = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:glob=""http://sap.com/xi/SAPGlobal20/Global""><soapenv:Header/>" &
            "<soapenv:Body>" &
                "<glob:RouteBundleMaintainRequest_sync_V1>" &
                    "<Route actionCode=""01"">" &
                        "<Name>tEST 250502</Name>" &
                        "<RouteTypeCode>2</RouteTypeCode>" &
                    "</Route>" &
                "</glob:RouteBundleMaintainRequest_sync_V1>" &
            "</soapenv:Body>" &
        "</soapenv:Envelope>"

        Return generatedXmlSchema
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks Alot.
`Dim myRequest As HttpWebRequest = CType(request, HttpWebRequest)
myRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"" ` Here also I am getting Warning `End of Statement Expected`

Comment: You are welcome. If I fulfilled your original question please mark the answer as accepted. You you found it useful you may want to up-vote it, too. As for the rest of your comment please explain.

Comment: now I saw your edit: try   `myRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\""utf-8\"""`

Comment: didn't I fulfilled your question?